# optimizing repetitive mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This script takes forever to run and sometimes it even crash the whole server

`shop_designs` has 3000+ entries and `shop_tshirts` has over 50k entries

How can i optimize it for faster execution ?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM shop_designs";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$design = $row["design_id"];
$rating = $row["rating"];
$hits = $row["hits"];
$retours = $row["returns"];
$sales = $row["sales"];
$plussales = $row["sales_plus"];
$featured = $row["featured"];
$created_timestamp = $row["created_timestamp"];
$returns = $row["returns"];
$wishlisted = $row["wishlisted"];
$vector = $row["vector"];
$sales = $sales + $plussales - $returns;

    if ($sales > 10) {
    $bonus = $sales * 100;
    } else {
        $bonus = $sales * 50;
    }

$unan = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
$unjour = 60 * 60 * 24;
$age_du_design = time() - $created_timestamp;
$age_du_design_en_jours = $age_du_design / $unjour;
$age_du_design_an = $age_du_design / $unan;
    if ($age_du_design < $unan) {
    $age_du_design = $unan;
    $age_du_design_an = "1";
    }

if ($sales == "1") {
$sales_per_year = $sales / $age_du_design_an;
} else {
$sales_per_year = $sales / $age_du_design_an;
}
    if ($sales < 1) {
    $sales_per_year = "0";
    }

$indicehits = ($hits / 1000) / 3;
$calculsales = $sales + $wishlisted - $retours;
$cote = $calculsales + $indicehits;
$cote = round($cote, 2);
if ($vector == "1") {
$cote * 1.25;
}


echo "Update D#$design.......";
$yquery = "UPDATE shop_designs SET rating='$cote', sales_per_year='$sales_per_year' WHERE design_id='$design'";
mysql_query($yquery) or die(mysql_error());

$rating_hits = $hits + $bonus;
$rating_hits = $rating_hits / 2;
$rating_hits = round($rating_hits);
$zyquery = "UPDATE shop_tshirts SET wishlisted='$wishlisted', rating='$cote', hits='$hits', rating_hits='$rating_hits',featured='$featured',tshirt_sales='$sales',sales_per_year='$sales_per_year' WHERE design_id='$design'";
mysql_query($zyquery) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: That's really a trivially small amount of records to be causing performance issues. I think the biggest issue is `SELECT * FROM shop_designs`. Why are you running this before you'er running two update queries? Could you not separate these?

Comment: because i need infos from shop_designs to do some maths to find the numbers needed in the updates of shop_designs and shop_tshirts

Comment: I think there is a reason but the whole thing is not shown in proper context. I think it is someone new to mysql that is having PHP do the heavy lifting @Ohgodwhy

Comment: The key to this seems to be the PHP code you've omitted. Your real solution is probably to rewrite the queries to perform whatever processing you're doing there themselves. Whether that's practical and what form it might take is impossible to say from what you have posted here.

Comment: i updated the post with the rest of the code, but it's a mess i warned you lol (a php noob wrote this, its a cron file ran each 24 hours but it takes sooooo long to run)... I have to do a lot of maths to find the values before updating the last 2 tables

Comment: How long does it take?  It's a bit of a mess but I don't see anything particularly wrong here.  I doubt there's much you can do to optimize those queries and I can't see any reason this whole routine should take more than 5 or 10 seconds of `shop_designs` has only approx 3000 rows.

Comment: i posted my comment 20 minutes ago, and the script is still running as we speak. It takes AT LEAST 30 minutes until it is finished

Comment: and it's on an OVH dedicated server with a lot of ram and good CPU

Comment: Instead of executing the update query inside the loop, try to append all update query onto a single string and execute it once.. this will reduce the overhead of accessing the DB by php on each loop..

Comment: not sure how to do that.. can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing each individual row, row by agonizing row (RBAR), is going to be slow. The design of this algorithm totally ignores the power of SQL to process *sets* of data.

How to redesign this for better performance: rewrite this to run fewer SQL `UPDATE` statements.

---

Before we get to that... there's some bizarre logic in the code. For example, what is the result of this:

```
 if ($vector == "1") {
 $cote * 1.25;
 }
```

We see `$cote` gets multiplied by `1.25`, but the return from that operation isn't stored anywhere. The result is discarded.

Why do we need a conditional test here:

```
 if ($sales == "1") {
 $sales_per_year = $sales / $age_du_design_an;
 } else {
 $sales_per_year = $sales / $age_du_design_an;
 }
```

So, if some condition is true, we assign a value to `$sales_per_year`. Otherwise, we assign the exact same value to `$sales_per_year`. Why do we need a conditional test?

And the whole rigmarole with the "age" in seconds, age in hours, age in years... that essentially boils down to returning the greatest of a) one year, or b) the calculated age in years.

The computation of `$calculsales` subtracts `$retours` (aka `$returns`) from `$sales`. That's not invalid, but it's kind of curious, because `$returns` has previously been subtracted from `$sales`.

---

With those issues aside, I don't see any operations here that can't be performed in SQL expressions, within a SQL statement.

For example:

```
 SELECT n.*
   FROM ( SELECT v.design_id
               , v.wishlisted
               , v.rating
               , v.hits
               , ROUND(v.hits + (v.sales * IF(v.sales > 10, 100, 50)) AS rating_hits
               , v.featured
               , v.sales
               , IF(v.sales < 1, 0, v.sales / v.age_du_design_an) AS sales_per_year
               , ROUND(v.sales + v.wishlisted - v.returns + v.hits/3000,2)
                 -- * CASE WHEN v.vector = 1 THEN 1.25 ELSE 1.00 END
                 AS cote
            FROM (
                   SELECT d.design_id
                        , d.rating
                        , d.hits
                        , d.featured
                        , (d.sales + d.plussales - d.returns) AS sales
                        , GREATEST((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-s.created_timestamp)/(60*60*24*365),1) AS age_du_design_an
                        , d.returns
                        , d.wishlisted
                        , d.vector
                     FROM shop_designs d
                 ) v
        ) n
```

But instead of fetching individual rows, and then issuing a bloatload of individual update statements, one for each `design_id`, we can do a `JOIN` operation between the query above, and the target table to be updated.

We can write that as a SELECT statement first, to test it. And then convert it to an UPDATE statement, something like this:

```
 UPDATE shop_tshirts t
   JOIN ( SELECT v.design_id
               , v.wishlisted
               , v.rating
               , v.hits
               , ROUND(v.hits + (v.sales * IF(v.sales > 10, 100, 50)) AS rating_hits
               , v.featured
               , v.sales
               , IF(v.sales < 1, 0, v.sales / v.age_du_design_an) AS sales_per_year
               , ROUND(v.sales + v.wishlisted - v.returns + v.hits/3000,2)
                 -- * CASE WHEN v.vector = 1 THEN 1.25 ELSE 1.00 END
                 AS cote
            FROM (
                   SELECT d.design_id
                        , d.rating
                        , d.hits
                        , d.featured
                        , (d.sales + d.plussales - d.returns) AS sales
                        , GREATEST((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-s.created_timestamp)/(60*60*24*365),1) AS age_du_design_an
                        , d.returns
                        , d.wishlisted
                        , d.vector
                     FROM shop_designs d
                 ) v
        ) n
     ON n.design_id = t.design_id
    SET t.wishlisted     = n.wishlisted
      , t.rating         = n.cote
      , t.hits           = n.hits
      , t.rating_hits    = n.rating_hits
      , t.featured       = n.featured
      , t.tshirt_sales   = n.sales
      , t.sales_per_year = n.sales_per_year
```

There's only one execution of that statement required, it will update all the rows in `shop_tshirts` in one fell swoop. We can do a similar operation for the other table as well.

That's how we get improved performance.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If you don't process the UPDATE as a *set*, and instead process row by agonizing row (RBAR), then be sure that you have suitable index defined on the `shop_tshirts` and `shop_designs` tables, with `design_id` as the leading column.

Answer (score 0):

I meant something like this

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM shop_designs";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
.
.
.
echo "Update D#$design.......";
$query += "UPDATE shop_designs SET rating='$cote', sales_per_year='$sales_per_year' WHERE design_id='$design';";
.
.
.

$query += "UPDATE shop_tshirts SET wishlisted='$wishlisted', rating='$cote', hits='$hits', rating_hits='$rating_hits',featured='$featured',tshirt_sales='$sales',sales_per_year='$sales_per_year' WHERE design_id='$design';";
}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

In you previous implementation php will access the db connection 6000+ times, but now php need to access it only two times... first to select the query and second to bulk update query.

**[EDIT]**
Also `$unan = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;` `$unjour = 60 * 60 * 24;` and `time()` can be put outside the loop. It will not create a noticeable memory difference, but it is more correct that way.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE shop_tshirts SET wishlisted='0', rating='2.18', hits='3550', rating_hits=' at line 1

Comment: Line1 is   UPDATE shop_designs SET rating='2.18', sales_per_year='0.227804419331' WHERE design_id='11074963'; UPDATE shop_tshirts SET wishlisted='0', rating='2.18', hits='3550', rating_hits='1800',featured='0',tshirt_sales='1',sales_per_year='0.227804419331' WHERE design_id='11074963';

Comment: mysql_query: "sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)"

Comment: @libertaire my mistake... it is not possible to ececute multiple queries through `mysql_query`, I think you need to use mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: i dont have mysqli installed on the server

Comment: This approach does *not* reduce the total number of UPDATE statements that need to be issued.